# How do you play with friends on minecraft classic

Tags: minecraft-classic-browser

How do I invite friends to my world in minecraft classic?

Answer (score 2):

When you open Minecraft Classic at https://classic.minecraft.net/, you will see a box containing a link. Click the copy button to copy the link to your clipboard. You can now share this link to a maximum of 9 friends, who can join your world and play together.

You can also find this link after you start playing in the world and hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the pause menu.

[image]